# Solving the Height of a Triangle at a Point

Tags: triangles

I just solved a right triangle with all the angles and measurements:

[image: Triangle With Approximate Measurements]

I want to find the height of the triangle at 2ft:

[image]

How would I find this and what would the height be?

Comment: In the second picture, the $2$ft at the bottom of the dashed line, what distance does it refer to? The distance from the right angle?

Comment: Yes, the distance from the bottom left point to the dotted line.

Comment: Then use similar triangles, or trig. We have $\frac{h}{2}\approx\frac{7.4641-2}{7.4641}$. Trig is a little nicer since we get an in principle exact answer.